# Render WordPress page builder blocks in Next.js / React.js?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js

Headless WordPress (CMS), that is use a page builder (Elementor, Gutenberg etc') to write content.

Then render the content elsewhere, using Next.js (React.js).

I can easily get the HTML markup, but the styling is challenging.
I could also get the inner data structure, for example Elementor is using JSON, but that means I should implement each component - unwanted.

How would you approach this, considering WP headless + Next.js is a requirement?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Combine the layouts from elementor and make them interactive with next / react...

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation - there's no easy solution. Page builders are dependent on lots of WP-specific code. Unless you need specific WP plugins to power parts of this, it's probably a lot less work to adapt ApostropheCMS to whatever your needs are.